# Fermion decay into axions

Tags: feynman-diagrams, fermions, axion

Do you know any literature on fermion decay into an axion and a lighter fermion?

I am especially interested in the dependence of the decay width on the initial fermion momentum. The momentum should appear in the vertex due to the derivative coupling of the axion to the fermions.

Is the decay suppressed or enhanced by large fermion momenta?

Comment: Isn't this process forbidden in axion theories?

Comment: Really? That's very interesting! Why is it forbidden?

Comment: Because axions are part of QCD and interact only with the "coloured part" of the standard model.